# Maven javadoc plugin 3.1.0 not generating aggregate javadocs

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, javadoc, maven-javadoc-plugin

I have a multi-module project for which I'd like to generate aggregate javadoc reports. I am using `maven-javadoc-plugin` version 3.1.0. Here's the reporting section of pom.xml file:

```
<reporting>
 <plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <reportSets>
      <reportSet>
        <id>non-aggregate</id>
        <reports>
          <report>javadoc</report>
        </reports>
      </reportSet>
      <reportSet>
        <id>aggregate</id>
        <inherited>false</inherited>
        <reports>
          <report>aggregate</report>
        </reports>
      </reportSet>
    </reportSets>
  </plugin>
 </plugins>
</reporting>
```

I am using `mvn site:site site:stage` goals to generate the javadoc reports. When I run this command, I expect to see `apidocs` directory containing `index.html` under `target/site/` but I don't see `apidocs` directory.

What's interesting is if I switch to `3.0.1` version of `maven-javadoc-plugin`, aggregate javadocs are successfully generated.

I understand that there was a change to how `aggregate` reports are generated in 3.1.0 as [documented here](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/examples/aggregate.html) and I have used the same reporting setup.

Also, javadocs for individual modules are generated correctly for both versions of the plugin.

Other details:

- JDK 8
- `maven-site-plugin` version 3.7.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found out what was causing this issue. I *suspect* that the cause was that in `maven-javadoc-plugin` version 3.1.0, there was a patch to fix [Support aggregated reports at each level in the multi-module hierarchy](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MJAVADOC-134).

This fix used the path defined in aggregator `pom.xml` to determine the outcome of [canGenerateReport()](https://maven.apache.org/components/plugins-archives/maven-javadoc-plugin-3.1.0/apidocs/org/apache/maven/plugins/javadoc/JavadocReport.html#canGenerateReport--).

After investigating the modules defined in my aggregator `pom.xml`, I found that my modules were defined as:

```
<modules>
    <module>./path/to/module1</module>
    <module>./path/to/module2</module>
    <module>./path/to/module3</module>
</modules>
```

The path had `./` in it that resulted in `canGenerateReport()` returning `false`. Removing `./` fixed the issue.

After the fix, my modules definition looks like:

```
<modules>
    <module>path/to/module1</module>
    <module>path/to/module2</module>
    <module>path/to/module3</module>
</modules>
```

Comment: Many thanks, my multi module project was not generating javadocs neither. In my case i was using plugin version 3.2.0 and my paths start with `../`. Using 3.0.2 makes it work.

Comment: In my case, the references did not work, because each `<module>` entry was pointing to the `pom.xml` file rather than the containing directory.